# Binomial Summation that Yields Factorial

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have the following finite summation: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{i+n} i^n {n \choose i}$$ that I've proven $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ to be equal to $n!$. However, I've noticed that if I introduce a constant $a$ into this summation as follows:$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i+n} (i+a)^n {n \choose i}$$ that the $a$'s all cancel out, and we are left again with $n!$ (I know this from Python and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=f%5C%2840%29k%5C%2841%29%20%3D%20Sum%5B%5C%2840%29nCr%5C%2840%29k%5C%2844%29%20j%5C%2841%29Power%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Cj%2Bk%5DPower%5B%5C%2840%29j%2Ba%5C%2841%29%2Ck%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bj%2C0%2Ck%7D%5D), not from mathematical proof). Is there any way to prove that this second summation is equivalent to the first one?

That is, show that the second summation is equal to $n!$ by proving the first summation is equal to the second.

I'm looking to show that the introduction of the $(i+a)$ does not affect the summation, and I want to show that the $+a$ will cancel out using the rules for manipulating summations.

I would greatly appreciate any help anyone could provide.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does this process generate the factorial of the exponent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078853).